# Windows Sub-System for Linux failure to load by fstab has failed to mount

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

> I'm serious, why people don't answer this

I don't know how to fix this error cuz I haven't used WSL for 2 years after the Windows update had a Massive critical issue...
anyone can solve this problem?

```dos
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3930]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         1

C:\Users\user>wsl
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount I:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount K:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount L:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return

C:\Users\user>wsl
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount I:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount K:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount L:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return

C:\Users\user>
```

also, my PC Spec is:

- Windows 10 Pro Build 22H2 (I updated recently)
- Intel Celeron 1005M 1.90GHz
- 8GB DDR3 RAM
- Drives:

  - Lexar 256GB SSD
  - I-O DATA SSPH-UA SCSI Disk Drive
  - KIOXIA TransMemory 32GB With Real Ubuntu disk image and data
- Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
- Internal GPU, Intel HD Graphics

I tried to fix this issue using YouTube, but that even not fixes.

Comment: It would be a good idea to find /etc/fstab and post it, formatted as code

Comment: i don't know where is linux root directory?

Comment: Can't tell you. I don't know if it's even real and not virtual ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Use the below command to fix it.

```
C:\Users\Usr> wsl --set-default Ubuntu
The operation completed successfully.
    
C:\Users\Usr> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
 
PS C:\Users\Usr> wsl
```

Hope this helps!